# What is the equivalent of Java's AbstractMap in C#?

Tags: c#, java, collections, dictionary

I need to create an object which exposes an `IDictionary<K,V>` interface, but I don't want to fill in the entire interface implemntation.

It would be nice to have the equivalent of Java's AbstractDictionary, which leaves you very little to impelment a complete dictionary (HashMap, in Java):

- If you don't need to iterate the collection, you have a single method to implement (TryGetValue)
- If you want it to be writeable, you implement another entry (Add).

Answer (score 4):

Wintellect's [PowerCollections library](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) includes a `DictionaryBase` class ([source code](https://powercollections.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Source/PowerCollections/DictionaryBase.cs)) that implements most of the standard IDictionary<K, V> interface. From the class' documentation comments:

> DictionaryBase is a base class that
>   can be used to more easily implement
>   the generic IDictionary<T> and
>   non-generic IDictionary interfaces.
>
> To use DictionaryBase as a base class,
>   the derived class must override Count,
>   GetEnumerator, TryGetValue, Clear,
>   Remove, and the indexer set accessor.

Answer (score 3):

`System.Collections.Generic` namespace contains three implementations of `IDictionary<K,V>`: `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, `SortedDictionary<TKey, TValue>` and `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question - AbstractDictionary is an abstract base skeleton implementation that you inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm building my own dictionary class, I inherit from System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection.

EDIT for all those who don't understand API design.

You should never, ever return a generic List or Dictionary from a public property or function. Insead you should return a class specially built for that purpose. This way you can add additional functionality to it later.

```
Dictionay<integer, Order> Orders() {get;}
CustomerOrders Orders() {get;}
```

With the second version you can do things like add a Total property and have the user actually find it.

In theory you could return a subclass of Dictionary that adds the Total property, but then the user would have to A. know you are doing it, and B. include a cast to get to the property.

Comment: Why not used the supplied dictionary class? are you pre ,NET 2?

Comment: ObjectModel.KeyedCollection is a .NET 2 feature specifically added for people making their own dictionary classes.

Comment: `KeyedCollection` should only be extended when the keys are derived from the values. IE: A person class might have a Social Security Number, or a database record would have a primary key. As such it is not always a suitable base class to use for Dictionaries.